# Angular 7 configuration or alternatives?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-cli, angular7

I have been struggling with how to implement Angular 7 into my .NET Core 2.X project keeping the best of both frameworks without success. The main problem that I am facing is that Angular wants to control my frontend and how it receives it. By this I mean it forces you to use static templates for everything, I get the concept but for my project, this is going to generate an insane amount of templates/components or templates with a bunch of unused display elements. It makes much much more sense to have more of a generic frontend component that receives the templates from the server then handle all the binding, DI, updates etc.

I have looked at several options and questions about Dynamic Components, Dynamic TemplateURL's, Custom Elements and lots of other topics. But the problem I see with most of these answers is that **none of them actually have a dynamic template**, they might use Dynamic Components but the actual loaded control still has a static template in the end.

[This question seems to be pointed to most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)

I did run across a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065289/1601882) that seemed to be an option but then I realized that it had to be run with the JIT Compiler. That again adds unnecessary load on the client when everything could be compiled ahead of time.

There was also one about using Angular Elements but this has its own [problems apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619736/multiple-angular-elements-from-different-scripts) and really doesn't fix the issues without allot of rewiring or other workarounds to keep everything working.

The Dynamic Component Loader sounded very promising, From the [Angular site](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) it states

> Component templates are not always fixed. An application may need to
>   load new components at runtime.

That implies that the templates may be set dynamically but at the same time, it implies that loading a new component at runtime will fix that. But the component loaded has a static template. Nowhere is the template generated or changed, or am I simply missing something?

I have looked at [Angular SSR](https://angular.io/guide/universal) and that almost handles it but I can't seem to figure out how to go through the Controller or otherwise utilize any of the benefits of .NET Core/ASP.NET or dynamic server-generated content. It seems to just offload the compiling from the client onto the server but still uses the same static templates. Is there a way of using Node.js to render a MVC Route then send the module?

There used to be a way to set the TemplateUrl of the Component to a Route on the Server but that is now not allowed, making a lot of the answers I have found obsolete but the exact way I would like to set this up.

The only real option I have been able to figure out is using MVC to generate Dynamic Modules/Components then load them in the Angular App. Would it be feasible to compile the .cshtml view via a controller to create an HTML string that is then used to Compile an Angular Module/Component then send that out to the Client and load it into the Angular App?

I understand how to compile my View into an html string but I am not sure how to go about Compiling the Angular Module or even if this is the right idea or if there is a better way of handling this?

It seems to me that this should be a fairly easy thing to do, all the tools seem to be there but not sure how to get things working right.

Comment: why using angular? You are about to disable most of all Angular's benefits. Probably you should look into direction of lightweight rendering library, like React or Vue instead.

Comment: @smnbbrv Basically my background has been with AngularJs, mainly the reason that I am trying to use Angular, I figured that since everything compiles down to JS in the end that I might be able to simply bypass Angular's control over the templates and just use what's pertinent to my app. I am not opposed to switching to another framework, actually was in my original question but took it out (didn't want to get off topic). I am not very familiar with React or Vue, do you know which one would be a better fit for my application given my end goals (lightweight, MVC etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

I recently started with Angular (After working with .net, jquery, javascript, react) and my first interaction is directly with angular 7. The first thing I noticed was how quickly I can develop in angular, but there are a lot of files which I am not even sure about, however are generated compare to react, but the learning curve was higher in react then in Angular definitely.

If you need something really lightweight, you should definitely go for libraries then framework. react is a good option, however it's not MVC driven and you will find it very different then Angular (I am realizing it from sometime).

Other than that, if most of my code is static, I could have chosen some kind of HTML template frameworks (i.e, nunjucks) which can be pre-compiled.

For components created in .net, I don't think that is possible to have them pre-compiled in angular, as you will only create something in .net if you need those component having dynamic data.