# Export Angular2 Component as standalone widget

Tags: angular, widget

Is there a way to export Angular2 Component as a standalone widget? I am aware it would probably require attaching angular2 core itself, that is not a problem (unless can be omitted).

My aim is to create a full app (system), which includes a shared component (like a product specific photo gallery). I would like that component to be exportable so somebody can include that on their page (which doesn't have to be Angular2).

Is that possible?

Comment: You can only export an Angular2 application as standalone widget. You can have multiple applications on the same page.

Comment: Would it be possible to export separate apps from a single code base? The full app + components (widgets)?

Comment: I don't know about that, I'm not using TS myself, only Dart and I don't know about building TS.

Comment: And would that be possible in Dart? I suspect it works the same way, as language should not define a feature.

Comment: Yes, I think it's quite the same in Dart.

Comment: Ok, the `angular-cli.json` has `apps` field with an array, so I guess it's possible to create multiple outputs. Thanks for help @günter-zöchbauer :).

Comment: did you find a solution to your question ?

Comment: Not really back then, haven't investigated the `apps` array further. However, with Angular 6 there comes the Angular Elements, which is a way to save Angular Components as native Custom Elements. More about it here: https://angular.io/guide/elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't available back when I asked the original question, but now it is possible to export Angular Components as Custom Elements using Angular Elements: https://angular.io/guide/elements